# What tags should be used for themes to show the type of layout?

Tags: theme-development, themes, tags, responsive

In the [Tag Filter](http://wordpress.org/themes/tag-filter/) the old tags 'fixed-width' and 'flexible-width' were renamed to 'fixed-layout' and 'fluid-layout'. Also new 'responsive-layout' tag appears.

**Should users duplicate new tag 'fluid-layout' with old tag 'flexible-width'?**

Or is it safe to use only new tags?

Answer (score 4):

Do not duplicate - just switch to the new tag as soon as 3.8 is released. The intent of this change is to replace the old tag, not to have both of them in use.